# How to set videojs currentTime for each video

Tags: jquery, button, video, video.js, forward

For a client I need to make a functional video playlist with 3 video's. I got them playing separately already, but now I need to make a custom skip button. I tried several things, but I keep getting a Console error "el.currentTime is not a function", "this.currentTime is not a function".

I tried to find some solutions on other forms, but everybody is actually making video players with id's. I want to prevent that to keep my code flexible.

```
$('video').each(function (i, el) {
    var p = $(el).parent();

        $('.forward-btn', p).click(function () {
            console.log("this video is skipped 5 seconds in" + el);
            el.currentTime(el.currentTime() + 10);
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you're running into here is that you're not actually initializing Videojs on these players, so you're not working with a reference to a Videojs instance, just a `video` tag.

You could either pass the `video` tag reference to a videojs constructor before using those methods, or use the native [HTML5 `currentTime` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/currentTime) setter instead.

```
// If you want to use the Videojs methods:
$('video').each(function (i, el) {
  var vjsEl = videojs(el);
  // ...
});

// Or, you can keep things as is and just use the `currentTime` attribute directly
console.log("this video is skipped 5 seconds in" + el);
el.currentTime = el.currentTime + 10; // notice this isn't a function.
```

If you go the Videojs constructor route, also keep in mind you'll need to make sure you clean up players (`dispose`) before removing the video tags from the DOM.

For what it's worth, just in case you haven't come across it, there's a well-maintained [videojs-playlist](https://github.com/brightcove/videojs-playlist) plugin. You're going to need to keep in mind the performance impact of using multiple `video` tags + Videojs instances like this (particularly for a large playlist), so at the very least you might want to take a look at their implementation.